# Pandas Taking columns from one data frame based on another data frame value

Tags: python-3.x

so I have been trying to get this for a while, but seem to be stuck. So I have two data frames in Pandas and they are of different sizes.

I want to take certain values from df2 and move them to df1 based on the values in the 'name' columns matching.

Here's an example, two data frames. We want df1 to get the 'color' and 'type' data from df2 for the respective values under 'name'.

df1:
Name Value

x     1

y      2

z      3

df2:

Name Value Color Type

z  10    blue  A

y  11     green B

x   12    yellow C

Result:
Name Value Color Type

x  1    yellow  C

y  2   green   B

z  3   blue    A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `merge` and join on Name, the drop Value_y:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Name',suffixes=('','_y')).drop('Value_y',axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Name  Value   Color Type
0    x      1  yellow    C
1    y      2   green    B
2    z      3    blue    A
```

Comment: Thank you! A slight extension on the original question: What if there are multiple columns I want to drop, say in the final data frame, I want to drop "color" as well as the "value" from the second data frame. So the final data frame has "name", "value" (from df1), and "type" (from df2).

Comment: @Xyvis if this answer helped you, would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) this answer.  Thank you.

Comment: .drop(['col1','col2'], axis=1) Use a list of column names.